# How to access to WordPress database from a mobile app?

Tags: php, android, database, wordpress

I have to make an Android mobile app for a website using [WordPress](https://wordpress.com).

How do I connect the WordPress DB to my app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The WordPress REST API provides API endpoints for WordPress data types that allow developers to interact with sites remotely by sending and receiving JSON (JavaScript Object Notation) objects.
https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/